# HTTP запрос с заголовком range

Tags: python, http, requests, header

Как Вы отправляете заголовок Range на сервер?

Так я делаю запрос на сервер:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'Range': 'bytes=8593-16273894'},  stream = True)
```

Вот что я вижу в headers:

```
{'date': 'Fri, 24 Sep 2021 22:23:31 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4', 'Content-Length': '11341032', 'last-modified': 'Sun, 22 Aug 2021 09:24:00 GMT', 'expires': 'Wed, 05 Jan 2022 16:39:29 GMT', 'cache-control': 'max-age=1641400769', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS', 'timing-allow-origin': '*', 'Content-Range': 'bytes 8593-16273894/16273894', 'x-cdn-diag': 'fra1-11045-5-28470-h-0-0---;11053-14-8234----0-0-1'}
```

Вопрос: почему же я не получаю отрезок видео который запрашиваю?

Comment: Вы отправляете `{'Range': 'bytes=8593-16273894'}`, а видите `'Content-Range': 'bytes 8593-16273894/16273894'`, правильно? А откуда вы видите тот заголовок? И как вы тот отрезок видео получаете? В вопросе увидел запрос с режимом потока, но не увидел считывание ответа. Отправил запрос в httpbin с включенным логированием и никаких изменений заголовка не происходило: https://pastebin.com/0QLgR50D

Comment: @gil9red вижу я Content-Range это заголовки которые поступили от сервера r.headers.

Я тут вот какое дело заметил я попробовал сохранить данные которые придут, в файл формата mp4 так как пытаюсь кусок видео сохранить, но фишка в том что файл становится не доступным после сохранения(хотя фрагмент видео-файла там есть, имеется ввиду фрагмент того отрезка который которые я передаю в Range). Как из переменной r правильно сохранить content в файл?

Comment: А никто не обещал что произвольные байты из середины видеофайла будут валидным mp4 файлом. Скорее даже наоборот

Comment: Alexey Ten ты прав.
Да я первые пол видео смог скачать и стримить на страницу, вторую половину я увы скачать не смог. Я вообще пытаюсь сделать перемотку на html player`е таким методом.

Comment: Так обычный html-тег video вполне сам умеет пкремотку

Comment: Alexey Ten умеет не спорю, но удалённое видео которое я транслирую на web-страницу оно загружается не с места куда я перемотал.

Объясню понятнее например есть на удалённом сервере mp4 файл весом 2GB я начинаю смотреть его на своей странице он у меня загрузился например на 500MB я перематываю на середину видео, и он у меня грузится не с середины а продолжает с 500MB доргужаться и пока он не загрузится условно на 1GB я не смогу продолжить смотреть видео, поэтому я и хочу получать отрезок видео чтобы при перемотке видео загружалось с нужного байта. И не могу понять как мне это сделать.